# Developing a Desktop Application for my college project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am new with Java and am interested in using J2EE for my next college project.  My question is how good (or possible) is it to use J2EE for desktop application.  Where do I start (easy to understand websites/ books)?  And is there a good free IDE for developing J2EE applications?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't use J2EE to develop desktop application. Usually, people use J2SE with Swing to develop Java Desktop Application. You can use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) to develop. Both of them are free. About books, I can recommend you some Java Swing book

[Java Swing tutorial](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-tutorial)

[Java Swing book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004088)

Comment: So is J2EE used predominately for web-based applications?  Because I am really interested in learinig J2EE.

Comment: yeah, J2EE is for Web App (Enterprise App). So, you can start learning J2EE for Web App with EJB and Servlet